# how is it possible for shared library to define a function but can't link to it?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

How is this possible:

```
>nm --defined-only foobar.so | grep foobar
000000000003c7c0 t foobar
>gcc foobar.c foobar.so
foobar.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `foobar'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Probably because foobar is local `(000000000003c7c0 _t_ foobar)`

Comment: @PeterL.  not so, I can "link" with a shared lib like that.  All this means, is that at runtime, the program will load the library then.  I verified with my own little library.

Comment: @Tibrogargan  what is the meaning of "local"?  Anyway, `foobar` is a "global" function.

Comment: The output of nm is "000000000003c7c0 t foobar".  The 't' says foobar is a local text symbol.  I believe nm :)

Comment: @Tibrogargan `t` just means, it is a function defined in the "text" area

Comment: If it was global in the text area, wouldn't it be a 'T'?

Comment: @Tibrogargan the output of `man nm` says   "T"
           "t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.

Comment: @Mark Galeck I'm not arguing about which area it's in.  It's quite clear it's in the text area.  The fact that it's a lower case 't' says it's a local symbol, not global - which is why he can't link against it.

Comment: Try `nm --defined-only foobar.so`

Comment: @Tibrogargan  I see.  Thank you!  But I still don't understand two things:  1.  how come `man nm` does not say anything about that  2.  What is "local"? - "static"?  My function is definitely not static.

Comment: @Mark Galeck  It does :)  At the top it explains that lowercase means local, uppercase means global.  Only global symbols are exported.

Comment: @PeterL  thank you for this suggestion!  same output , I updated the question

Comment: @Tibrogargan I see, thank you again!

Comment: foobar is a function, yes?  Did you declare it?  (And forget to actually write the code, or have a typo in the name?)

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes and it is not static

Comment: @Tibrogargan  well I think your comment answers my question, I upvoted the comment but you can make it answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link to "foobar" because foobar.so defines "foobar" as a local symbol in the "text" area and only global symbols are exported

The 2nd column of the output of nm gives the symbol type.  lowercase means local, uppercase means global. Only global symbols are exported.  See [man nm(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)

Answer (score 0):

On top of excellent @Tibrogargan answer, you may try to check binding using `readelf` utility, it is a bit more clear wrt global vs local symbols - it will actually print GLOBAL or LOCAL

```
> readelf --symbols foobar.so
```